# Find AM Times and update?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In the mySQL Table, I have a field called CallTime (`TIME` format)

How do I find all the AM times and update time to 13:00:00 ?

Comment: This should be trival.  If you're simply storing the time stamp, without a date, you should only need to look for time stamps less than 13:00 and update accordingly.  Is there some aspect more complex to this question you didn't mention?

Comment: Unless there's an issue about time zones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update table set calltime = '13:00:00' where calltime <= '12:00:00'
```